# Como aplicar as classes de validação de entrada de formulário do bootstrap v4 com a sintaxe ASP.NET Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

Segue código:

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Telefone, new { @class = "font-weight-bold" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telefone, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Digite seu telefone" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Telefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Aqui está um exemplo do bootstrap v4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#server-side

Eles utilizam a classe `is-invalid` e `is-valid`. Como faço isso em Razor ?

Comment: você quer fazer isso para que após o post, ao retornar com a validação aplique a classe ou você se refere a marcar como válido em tempo real via javascript?

Comment: Quero fazer com Client-Side. (tempo real via javascript)